# IMPORTXML with search and JSON data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this code on a website

```
<div id="productPriceJSON_18678511"  style="display:none;">
        [{
            "isXPromoProd":"true",
            "mfPartNumber":"961576-BLACK",
            "productGroupId":"18678008",                
            "productId" : "18678511",
            "listPrice" :"$85.00",
            "offerPrice" :"$85.00",
            "discountPrice" :"$42.50",
            "lowestPriceAmount" :"$42.50",
            "highestPriceAmount" :"$42.50",
            "colorCount" : "0",
            "isPriceVary" :"false"
            }]
    </div>
```

There are different DIVs with different SKU variable productPriceJSON_18678522, productPriceJSON_18678533,productPriceJSON_18678544 and so on.

I want to do 2 things:

1. Import all the DIVs that contain productPriceJSON_, I tried using

   //div[@id=[contains(.,"skuPriceJSON_")]]

But no luck

2. How can I get the discount price from this DIV matching $42.50?

Really appreciate the help here.

Cheers,
B.

Comment: In order to test your situation with your xpth, can you provide the sample URL?

Comment: Well, for the first one I figured it out. I was using the wrong logic. It works with
`//div[contains(@id, 'skuPriceJSON_')]`

Still need help with the 2nd one though please :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users how have the same issue.